# Submenu not clickable in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, superfish, submenu, clickable

On my website http://www.mvl.eu I used superfish for a submenu. The submenu IS visible (z-index problem), but is is not clickable, because it disappears if you move to the sublinks.
This problem only happens in IE9, until IE8 there was no problem. Can someone please tell me what the problem is, because i'm pretty out of ideas.
Thanx!

Comment: Have you set a z-index for the <ul> tag or the <li> tag?

Comment: For: .sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just checked your website, I can confirm this is also an issue on IE7, unless you move the mouse down fast enough. Looks like there is some kind of gap between the definition of the menu title, and the menu items. Perhaps the issue is when the mouse is in this gap?

Comment: The small gap is there in all browsers. If you move over it a bit faster it's no problem. In IE9 however it is not possible to move over the gap without losing the submenu like it seems.

Comment: I closed the gap you mentioned en it seems like this fixed the problem. Maybe IE9 handles moving over the gap in a different way than other versions. Maybe IE9 doesn't apply a delay, thus immediately letting the submenu disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the help. Let me partly answer my own question. The problem in IE9 is that all the javascript / Jquery elements on my website don't work anymore. The superfish submenu had a little gap between the link and the submenu, but in javascript there was a delay of a second before the menu disappeared, enough to cross the little gap. Without javscript the delay was 0 sec, so as soon as you entered the gap with the mouse, the submenu disappeared. I positioned the submenu right next to the link so the problem is fixed and the menu works even with javascript disabled.
The real question is why these javascript / jquery elements like lightbox, superfish and nivoslider don't work in IE9.